# How to disable WakaTime API Key popup upon start-up?

Tags: phpstorm, wakatime

Whenever I start up PhpStorm I get this pop-up to enter a "WakaTime API Key". Is there an option to disable this since I have no use for it (it's an empty textbox and I just press it away every time).

Comment: WakaTime is a 3rd party plugin (not made by JetBrains). Either configure that plugin properly ... or disable it (if you do not use it). https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7425-wakatime -- author contact details and other links are at the bottom.

Comment: see https://github.com/wakatime/jetbrains-wakatime/issues/121#issue-441758699 - looks as if this prompt is only shown if there is no `.wakatime.cfg` file in your home directory